# Highchart Y-Axis Scale Values Missing

Tags: highcharts

If you look at the JSFiddle below, you'll see that when it renders the chart, the upper-most values are not displayed on the chart (10,000/10,000/80,0000/20,0000).

I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't display those top values.

I also noticed that it doesn't display the -20,000 value for the Weight channel.

https://jsfiddle.net/BBousman/h4gs7erk/

```
-
```

Comment: You have defined the min value to be -20,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `showLastLabel` option:

```
yAxis: [{
    ...,
    showLastLabel: true
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/142uc9Ls/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.showLastLabel

Comment: That took care of the higher values but why does the -20,000 Weight value not display? I tried showFirstLabel: true but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hi @BBousman, You need to set `startOnTick: true`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b17r54jv/

Comment: Thank you sir! That fixed it!